# Is "more informed decisions" or "better informed decisions" the more correct form?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing some copy for a marketing campaign that promotes the use of a software testing tool by demonstrating how the results of the tool provide you with a greater wealth of information on which to make business decisions.

In relation to this, I'm using the term "informed decisions" and my initial wording included the phrase "help you make more informed decisions".

The phrase "more informed decisions" is one that is common to me and from a Google search appears to be common in the context in which I am using it, that is to denote that with additional evidence a decision can be more informed than without.

I considered whether this phrase runs the risk of being misinterpreted or being confusing due to a slight ambiguity.

The phrase "more informed decisions" could be interpreted as meaning decisions that are more greatly informed, or it could be interpreted as a greater number of informed decisions (e.g. here is *one* informed decision, here are *more* informed decisions).

I then considered the phrase "better informed decisions". I feel this has the same intended meaning but removes the above ambiguity. It could refer to decisions that are better informed or it could refer to informed decisions that are better. Both are on subject and would be fine to me.

A quick Google search suggested that the phrase "more informed decisions" is significantly more commonly used than "better informed decisions".

I have a feeling that "better informed" is more grammatically-correct than "more informed" although I have no formal basis for this.

Out of the phases "more informed decisions" and "better informed decisions", is there a more correct form?

Comment: It's not a matter of "more grammatically correct". Both expressions are really just [post-war management/marketing "jargon"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=better+informed+decisions%2Cmore+informed+decisions&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But as that link shows, "more is more", regardless of whether anyone can make a grammatical case for "better is better".

Comment: I agree. What is grammatically correct often isn't relevant to what will work best with the intended audience.

Comment: Indeed. It's probably ***better** to use the **more*** common version, rather than ***more** accurate to use the grammatically **better*** version.

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+informed+decision%2Cbetter+informed+decision&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: From least to most common: Better -> More -> Well. Well-informed is the most commonly seen; if google is a measure of how common something is.

Answer (score 5):

Use "better-informed."  In this context, "better" modifies "informed," so those two words should be hyphenated.

Please see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-informed

Comment: I'll compromise and opt for "more-informed"

Comment: @JonCram Those would be decisions made on the basis of an increased quantity of information, rather than on the basis of increased quality of information -- does the tool provide greater quantity or greater quality of information?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Neither, really. The tool provides additional information that is currently quite time-consuming to collect manually. With such information available a user is in a position to make a more suitable decision than without. The tool provides additional information which allows the user to make higher quality decisions.

Answer (score 1):

They are both equally correct and equally ambiguous. *Better informed decisions* could be read either as decisions that are better informed or as better (informed) decisions. It is just as ambiguous as *more informed decisions* and for the same reason. In each case, the adverb (*better* or *more*) could apply to either *informed* or *decisions*.

So, since both versions are ambiguous, go for the most common one. Personally, for example, I would immediately understand *more informed decisions* as decisions that are more informed while I may well parse *better informed decisions* as decisions that are equally informed but better.

Comment: It would be rare that better decisions were not well informed decisions, but many people make more decisions that are not well informed.

Comment: No, there is the added complication with 'more' that it may be a quantifier as well as an intensifier.

Answer (score 1):

Neither better nor more implies that something has reached a tolerable level of goodness.

`Well-informed` is the normal way of saying what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

As to marketing, since "more" is not necessarily better, I'd go for "better-informed".

Answer (score 0):

Marketing copy needs to be read and not glanced over.

Hence I suggest you use "better informed" decisions. Here the reader is much more likely to read both better and informed as separate words and hence pay more attention, as he would consciously make the connection.

"More informed" is a much-read phrase and shall not act as a differeciator.It has been read...everybody says it and hence, does not mean much.The mind glosses over it and hence the reader is less likely to be affected.

Another alternative could be "more, better-informed decisions"where more could refer to the number and better to the quality of decisions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is "more informed decisions" or "better informed decisions" the more correct form?

First point: correct is ungradeable - it is either correct or not.

Second point "**more**" indicates quantity; "**better**" indicates quality. The two do not necessarily go together. As there are two meanings, they are basically incomparable.

If you are choosing "**informed decisions**" as your noun phrase to be qualified, "**more**" would indicate that, instead of making only 30 decisions a day, you can now make 50 decisions a day.

**Better** would indicate that, if, of the 30 decisions, 20 were bad, now only 10 would be bad.

The problem you have is that "more" and "better", idiomatically would modify only "**informed**" and not "**informed decisions**". This seems to put an end to your using either, and you need to rephrase.

Better {informed decisions} = "informed decisions that are solidly backed by high[er] quality intelligence."

More {informed decisions} = "a greater quantity/percentage of informed decisions."

The big advantage that you have is that "**more informed decisions**" and "**better informed decisions**" are, at their natural reading, nebulous concepts that sound desirable.

It is highly unlikely that anyone reading the blurb will analyse the English and, even if they do, nobody is going to be able to sue you.

Based on this last observation - either is fine. You could even say "**More and better** informed decisions"